# Are there any jurisdictions in the US that require public school students to learn Spanish?

Tags: united-states, immigration, education, languages

As the amount of Spanish-speaking Americans is increasing, do some towns, counties, or states mandate all public school students to learn at least some Spanish?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by mandate learning Spanish? Do you mean as in everyone is required to take it or that they are required to offer it as an option?

Comment: Why the downvote? I would like to improve if possible

Comment: Does that mean that all students are required to take some Spanish or just that they offer it? There are plenty of things that get taught at school that not all students are required to take. This information should be edited into your question so that it is more clear what you are asking. As far as I am aware Spanish is one of the foreign languages taught in many schools but no one is required to take it but they may be required to take a foreign language from the ones offered.

Comment: @JoeW, corrected.

Comment: Question looks much better now!

Comment: The question and title still don't quite match

Comment: I know from personal experience that requiring *some* non-English language (and/or ESL, for students who do not speak English as a first language) is fairly typical. I don't know of any school district that mandates Spanish in particular, but there are [a lot of them](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+many+school+districts+in+the+us) and it's hard to make categorical statements about all of them at once.

Comment: The obvious one is Puerto Rico. I'm not sure if you intended to include it.

Comment: I had to learn Spanish in my school in England in the 1960s. A modern language was part of the curriculum. There was no option to choose another language. My sister, at a different school, did German.

Answer (score 9):

Many states like [New York](http://www.nysed.gov/world-languages/graduation-requirements) and [Texas](https://texreg.sos.state.tx.us/public/readtac$ext.TacPage?sl=T&app=9&p_dir=N&p_rloc=191356&p_tloc=&p_ploc=1&pg=2&p_tac=&ti=19&pt=2&ch=74&rl=11) require some study of a language other than English. They don't specify that this should be Spanish, but Spanish is by far the most common. [California](https://www.cde.ca.gov/ci/gs/hs/cefhsgradreq.asp) requires either a foreign language or visual/performing arts. In all cases, these requirements are limited to a year or two at most.

As mentioned in the comments on the question, public school students in Puerto Rico are obviously required to learn Spanish as it is the primary language of instruction there. English is also a required subject at all levels.

Comment: I would imagine that some smaller schools with limited resources might only offer Spanish as a foreign language, so the answer is probably "yes".

Comment: That was certainly the case with the district I graduated from in 1996 (class had about 40 students and was the only HS in the district).